# Error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token

Tags: c, syntax

maybe it's a simple question, because i'm starting C programming in linux. 
I'm developing a client/server program, and when i'm trying to add a user, the GCC give me this error: "server.c:71:16: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token" and i can't understand where is the problem. The 71th line is when i call the function AddUser.

```
int main(){

    int fifo_1,fifo_2,i,num_args, status_triage, users_verify, login=0;
    char name_fifo[20], comand[20], arg_1[20], arg_2[20], username[20];
    struct request req;
    users_list list = NULL;

    //LOGIN CYCLE
    do{

        if(strcmp(req.str, "exit") == 0) // If the user inserts "exit"
        {
            printf("check1\n"); 
            req.type = -1;
        }

        else // Add user
        {
            if(num_users < 4)
            {
                users_list = AddUser (list, req);
            }
            else if(num_users == 4) // The program has the maximum number of players
                    req.type=2; 
        }   

}while(req.login == 0);
```

I don't know if it's necessary, but i put the AddUser function as well:

```
users_list AddUser(users_list list, req req){

        users_list new, aux;

        new = malloc(sizeof(users_list));

        if (new == NULL){
            printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        strcpy(new->username, req.str);
        new->pid = req.pid;

        new->next = NULL;

        if (list == NULL)
            list = new;

        else{
            aux = list;
            while (aux->next != NULL)
                aux = aux->next;
            aux->next = new;
            }
            num_users++;

        return list;
}
```

Thank's for the time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
users_list = AddUser (list, req);
```

is meaningless. `users_list` is a type name. You can't assign anything to a type.

You used that type name to declare a variable above

```
users_list list = NULL;
```

Wasn't it your intent to use that variable, as in

```
list = AddUser (list, req);
```

?

Based on the implementation of `AddUser` this is exactly how you are supposed to use it: it returns the new list head pointer value.

---

Another problem in your code is memory allocation in `AddUser`

```
new = malloc(sizeof(users_list));
```

`users_list` is evidently a *pointer* type. I don't know what type it points to, since you are not showing your definition of `users_list` (is it a pointer to `req`?), but in any case `sizeof(users_list)` gives you the size of a *pointer*. This is obviously incorrect. You need `sizeof` of the pointed object, not of the pointer. I'd change it into

```
new = malloc(sizeof *new);
```

and recommend avoiding using `sizeof(type)` in the future as much as possible. Prefer to use `sizeof expression` instead. In general, memory allocation should look as follows

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer);
```

That should help you to avoid such `sizeof` errors.

Comment: thank's for the solution! 
Actually, after fix it, i runned the code, and when i was trying to add a user, the server showed me this error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Do you have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: @MarcodeBarbosa use gdb to find your bug. You can't write any significant amount of C code without knowing how to use it, so start now.

Comment: @MarcodeBarbosa: See the answer for additional `malloc` problem.

Comment: @JimBalter, you are right! I'm gonna follow your advice, thank's!

Comment: @AndreyT, one more time, thank's for the explanation & solution!